# Unable to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, video, youtube

I've burnt **Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-bit** on DVD-R by Infra Recorder, and created a live USB of 15.10 64-bit using Universal USB Installer.

Then I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-bit, or Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit alongside windows 10, but I keep getting these errors:

---

With no parameter `nomodeset` (transcribed from [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRub20RL6Uc) given in original post):

```
[  0.033675] Ignoring BGRT: Invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[  3.205412] nouveau E[ PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] failed to load fuc409c
[  3.211068] nouveau E[  PFIFO][0000:01:00.0] unsupported engines 0x00000001
[  3.211138] nouveau E[    DRM] failed to create kernel channel, -22
[ 34.856110] ata8.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen
[ 34.856130] ata8: SError: { RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake 10B8B Dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStaTrns UnrecFIS DevExch }
[ 34.856164] ata8.00: failed command:IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
[ 34.856178] ata8.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 2 pio 512 in
[ 34.856178]          res 40/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)
[ 34.856209] ata8.00: status: { DRDY }
```

---

With parameter nouveau.modeset=0 or nomodeset: (transcribed from [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TpxkmrFp9g):

```
[  0.033675] Ignoring BGRT: Invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[ 34.856110] ata8.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen
[ 34.856130] ata8: SError: { RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake 10B8B Dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStaTrns UnrecFIS DevExch }
[ 34.856164] ata8.00: failed command:IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
[ 34.856178] ata8.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 2 pio 512 in
[ 34.856178]          res 40/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)
[ 34.856209] ata8.00: status: { DRDY }
```

---

**My PC specs:**

- MOBO: Asus Z97-Pro
- CPU: Intel i7 4790K
- GPU: Asus GTX970 Strix

Comment: What kind of errors? Please include more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `nouveau.modeset=0` instead `nomodeset`.

The issue that you have is a kind of incompatibility between *nouveau* open source driver and some Nvidia graphic cards.

I've got the same problem with a PC with a Nvidia GTX950M: `nomodeset` didn't work, but `nouveau.modeset=0` worked.

P.S. once you have installed Ubuntu, to keep things working, you have to add `nouveau.modeset=0` to grub configuration file or blacklist *nouveau* driver.

**My solution that solved my problem:**

change grub configuration file opening it as administrator:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add nouveau.modeset=0 to the following line as showed:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
```

then save with `ctrl+o` and exit with `ctrl-x`. Now you have to update grub with the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I hope to be useful.

Comment: im no have inastalled ubuntu, how i can change configuration file of grub.

Comment: @Kacper First edit grub as you have done in the second video. Then, if you succeed to boot and install Ubuntu, reboot system (and eventually edit another time the grub during boot). Only when you have Ubuntu working you can change grub configuration file permanently.

Comment: nouveau.modeset=0 does not help are the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to switch slots.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, for solution your problem must install the last distro of ubuntu, NO 14.04, i dont know why, but didn't recognise the new root of folders than use windows 10, so the partition didn't know where is the point of start on the disc for install ubuntu on 14.04, i believe than the wizard install of 14.04 were a deprecated script, so when u install from a usb or from a disc already u make a copy from the iso of 14.04 a script before from the release of windows 10. obviously that script did not have support for that NEW OS

Comment: -1 The Nouveau driver supports Nvidia's Maxwell chips (GTX 970/980) since kernel v3.19 which was shipped with Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.0. It should be fine in 14.04.4.